# On a Mac, can I close windows from the dock?

Tags: windows, mac, dock

It is such a pain to open the window from the dock, just so I can close it. Surely there is a way to close it without opening it, and I am just missing the trick. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to quit an application, all you have to do if hover over the icon with the mouse, right click then click quit.

But if you're trying to close a minimized window of an application, there's isn't a way to do it that I'm aware of without bringing back the windows from minimized.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, closing a window (usually a Safari window) from the minimized state is what I want to do. It is a feature I really, really miss from my PC.